# How to copy a file to every directory with Grunt?

Tags: gruntjs

So I'm building a WP plugin and it's customary to put empty index.html files into every folder to prevent directory listing where the host allows it. I'm building the deployment-ready package with grunt, but the only thing I'm missing are these files. I have many folders and would rather not create these files by hand. I'm happy to create one, and make Grunt copy that file to every path. But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No additional grunt plug-ins are necessary. Your requirement can be achieved using Grunt's built-in features.

Consider adding a [custom Task](https://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#custom-tasks) to your `Gruntfile.js` as per the one named `createEmptyHtmlFiles` shown below.

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    // ...
  });

  /**
   * Custom task to create empty `index.html` file in all folders.
   */
  grunt.registerTask('createEmptyHtmlFiles', function() {

    var fileName = 'index.html',
        contents = '';

    grunt.file.expand({ filter: 'isDirectory' }, 'dist/**/*')
        .forEach(function(dirPath) {
          var htmlFilePath = dirPath + '/' + fileName;
          grunt.file.write(htmlFilePath, contents, { encoding: 'utf8'})
        });
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['createEmptyHtmlFiles']);

};
```

**Explanation:**

1. Typically your `Gruntfile.js` will include `grunt.initConfig({ ... });` section that defines the configuration of various Tasks that you want to perform. This part should remain as per your current configuration.
2. A custom Task named `createEmptyHtmlFiles` is registered that does the following:

   - Assigns the desired filename, i.e. `index.html`, to the `fileName` variable and also assigns an empty string to the `contents` variable.
   - Next we utilize [`grunt.file.expand`](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand) to which we pass a [globbing pattern](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns). In the example above the glob provided is `'dist/**/*'`. The globbing pattern combined with the `filter: 'isDirectory'` option essentially obtains the pathnames to all folders inside the `dist` directory.

     **Important:** This glob pattern you will need to change as per your directory structure.
   - Next we iterate each directory pathname using the Array's [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.
   - In each turn of the `forEach` loop we assign to the `htmlFilePath` variable a new pathname for where the resultant `index.html` file is to be created.
   - Each `index.html` file is created using [`grunt.file.write`](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.write).

**Demo:**

1. Lets say the project directory is structured as follows:

   ```
   .
   ├── Gruntfile.js
   ├── dist
   │   ├── a
   │   │   ├── b
   │   │   │   └── 1.txt
   │   │   └── c
   │   │       └── 2.txt
   │   ├── d
   │   │   ├── 3.txt
   │   │   └── e
   │   │       └── 4.txt
   │   └── f
   │       └── g
   │           └── 5.txt
   ├── node_modules
   │   └── ...
   └── package.json
   ```
2. Given the `Gruntfile.js` above after running `$ grunt` it will change to the following:

   ```
   .
   ├── Gruntfile.js
   ├── dist
   │   ├── a
   │   │   ├── b
   │   │   │   ├── 1.txt
   │   │   │   └── index.html         <-----
   │   │   ├── c
   │   │   │   ├── 2.txt
   │   │   │   └── index.html         <-----
   │   │   └── index.html             <-----
   │   ├── d
   │   │   ├── 3.txt
   │   │   ├── e
   │   │   │   ├── 4.txt
   │   │   │   └── index.html         <-----
   │   │   └── index.html             <-----
   │   └── f
   │       ├── g
   │       │   ├── 5.txt
   │       │   └── index.html         <-----
   │       └── index.html             <-----
   ├── node_modules
   │   └── ...
   └── package.json
   ```

   **Note** Every folder inside the `dist` directory now includes an empty `index.html` file.
3. You may need to exclude the `index.html` from being created in specific directories. In which case we can you can negate specific directories via the glob pattern(s) passed to the `grunt.file.expand` method.

   For instance, lets say we configure it as follows in the `createEmptyHtmlFiles` task:

   ```js
   ...
   grunt.file.expand({ filter: 'isDirectory' }, ['dist/**/*', '!dist/a/{b,c}'])
   ...
   ```

   **Note:** This time we pass an Array that contains two glob patterns. The first one is the same as per the previous example, however the second one begins with `!` which will negate a match.

   Running `$ grunt` using the the aforementioned glob patterns will result in the following directory structure:

   ```
   .
   ├── Gruntfile.js
   ├── dist
   │   ├── a
   │   │   ├── b
   │   │   │   └── 1.txt              
   │   │   ├── c
   │   │   │   └── 2.txt              
   │   │   └── index.html             <-----
   │   ├── d
   │   │   ├── 3.txt
   │   │   ├── e
   │   │   │   ├── 4.txt
   │   │   │   └── index.html         <-----
   │   │   └── index.html             <-----
   │   └── f
   │       ├── g
   │       │   ├── 5.txt
   │       │   └── index.html         <-----
   │       └── index.html             <-----
   ├── node_modules
   │   └── ...
   └── package.json
   ```

   **Note** Every folder inside the `dist` directory, excluding folders `b` and `c`, now include an empty `index.html` file.

---

**btw.** When you say *"empty index.html files"*, I've taken that literally. However if you did need some html markup in each file you can assign that to the `contents` variable. For example:

```js
contents = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head></head>\n<body></body>\n</html>';
```

---

#### But I said *"copy a file ..."*

In which case you can change the custom Task to the following:

```js
/**
  * Custom task to copy a source `index.html` file in all folders.
  */
 grunt.registerTask('copyFileToFolders', function() {

   var srcFilePath = './path/to/file/to/copy/index.html';

   grunt.file.expand({ filter: 'isDirectory' }, 'dist/**/*')
       .forEach(function(dirPath) {
         grunt.file.copy(srcFilePath, dirPath + '/index.html')
       });
 });
```

**Notes:**

- This utilizes [`grunt.file.copy`](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.copy) to copy the source file to all folders.
- The pathname assigned to the `srcFilePath` variable should be substituted with a real pathname to the actual master `index.html` file that you want to copy to all folders.
- As per the first example, the glob pattern passed to `grunt.file.expand` must be change as necessary.